# Does the symfony form fields initialize to null if not visible

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have few  fields on the form like `name`, `description`, `timestamp`.
Now in the form I am only displaying name and description but not timestamp.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->setTimestamp(new \DateTime());
}
```

Now in my database, it is coming as null.

Either doctrine is not executing constructor or those fields are set to null when displayed in form.
Even though I am not displaying them.

Comment: Is your timestamp-property not included in the form or is it set as a hidden-field?

Comment: I am using `{{form_row(form.name)}}` in template. so i am only displaying required fields. they are not in form. i don't know if they are hidden or not

Comment: Well, if time stamp is not in your form then it's not going to end up in your entity.  Need to add it as a hidden field.  However, I suspect that you really want the entity to take care of time stamping itself.  Maybe not.  Depends on your use case.

Comment: why can't i just add it in constructor?

Comment: Can you show the `setTimestamp()` from your Entity and the action(s) working within your form in your Controller? I'm assuming there is either an error in `setTimestamp($timestamp)` or in the way you create the form. If you don't have a field for the property in your form, it will not be touched, therefore the timestamp should keep its default value. Maybe you can try the following: `$test = new EntityClass(); var_dump($test->getTimestamp());` to see whether the timestamp is actually set on `__construct()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need put the timestamp field in your FormType.

If you don't need to show it, just hide the field and set default value.

Something like that:

```
$builder->add('timestamp', 'hidden', array(
    'data' => new \DateTime(),
));
```

Don't forget `{{form_rest(form)}}` at end of the twig template to send all hidden fields.

Comment: But then what if i use friebug and change that value

Comment: The validation of your requests need to be on client and on server. The server validation should prevent this kind of actions with firebug. Search about it =)